# Converting a Two's complement number to its binary representation

Tags: javascript, floating-point, binary, numbers, twos-complement

I am performing bitwise operations, the result of which is apparently being stored as a two's complement number. When I hover over the variable it's stored in I see- `num = -2086528968.`

The binary of that number that I want is - `(10000011101000100001100000111000)`.

But when I say `num.toString(2)` I get a completely different binary representation, the raw number's binary instead of the 2s comp(-1111100010111011110011111001000).

How do I get the first string back?

Link to a converter: rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html 
Put in this number: -2086528968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pedro already answered this, but since this is a hack and not entirely intuitive I'll explain it.

> I am performing bitwise operations, the result of which is apparently being stored as a two's complement number. When I hover over the variable its stored in I see `num = -2086528968`

No, the result of most bit-operations is a 32bit **signed** integer. This means that the bit `0x80000000` is interpreted as a sign followed by 31 bits of value.

The weird bit-sequence is because of how JS stringifies the value, something like `sign + Math.abs(value).toString(base)`;

How to deal with that? We need to tell JS to *not* interpret that bit as sign, but as part of the value. But how?

An easy to understand solution would be to add `0x100000000` to the negative numbers and therefore get their positive couterparts.

```js
function print(value) {
  if (value < 0) {
    value += 0x100000000;
  }
  console.log(value.toString(2).padStart(32, 0));
}

print(-2086528968);
```

Another way would be to convert the lower and the upper bits seperately

```js
function print(value) {
  var signBit = value < 0 ? "1" : "0";
  var valueBits = (value & 0x7FFFFFFF).toString(2);

  console.log(signBit + valueBits.padStart(31, 0));
}

print(-2086528968);


//or lower and upper half of the bits:
function print2(value) {
  var upperHalf = (value >> 16 & 0xFFFF).toString(2);
  var lowerHalf = (value & 0xFFFF).toString(2);
  console.log(upperHalf.padStart(16, 0) + lowerHalf.padStart(16, 0));
}

print2(-2086528968);
```

Another way involves the "hack" that pedro uses. You remember how I said that *most* bit-operations return an `int32`? There is one operation that actually returns an **unsigned** *(32bit)* interger, the so called [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift)).

So `number >>> 0` does not change the bits of the number, but the first bit is *no longer* interpreted as sign.

```js
function uint32(value){
  return value>>>0;
}

function print(value){
  console.log(uint32(value).toString(2).padStart(32, 0));
}

print(-2086528968);
```

> will I run this shifting code only when the number is negative, or always?

generally speaking, there is no harm in running `nr >>> 0` over positive integers, but be careful not to overdo it.

Technically JS only supports Numbers, that are `double` values *(`64bit floating point` values)*. Internally the engines also use `int32` values; where possible. But no `uint32` values. So when you convert your negative `int32` into an `uint32`, the engine converts it to a `double`. And if you follow up with another bit operation, first thing it does is converting it back.

So it's fine to do this like when you need an actual `uint32` value, like to print the bits here, but you should avoid this conversion between operations. Like "just to fix it".

Comment: should i choose yours or his as the answer? Clearly yours is more thorough.

Comment: The one that YOU feel that it best answers the question.

Comment: In the second example, wouldn't the value in the parentheses when you are setting the valueBits potentially be negative, and thus yield 1-1(etc.) as you have said the Stringify will put a negative in front then display the rest of the bits as the value

Comment: `(value & 0x7FFFFFFF)` can not be negative as it is excluding the bit that would contain the negative sign.

Comment: I was worried that it would just interpret the first bit in 7FFFFFFF as a negative indicator, potentially, but then i realized it places the result of 0x7FFFFFFF into a 32 bit integer so your reply is quite right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Follow bellow the result:

```js
var number = -2086528968;
    
    var bin = (number >>> 0).toString(2)
    //10000011101000100001100000111000
    console.log(bin)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Because shifting a number zero positions does not change it! Or does it? Or in other terms, what you're doing is a hack. Please explain the hack so OP and future readers also understand how/why this is working.

Comment: also, will I run this shifting code only when the number is negative, or always?

Comment: @a_here_and_now you can run it always, it's probably as quick if not qicker as the check wether the number is negative; and it does nothing to positive ints.